# Delete entity revision does not delete from field_data table

Tags: 8, entities

I created a custom entity, I can edit, save, delete, create revisions and revert. I adapted the code from node module to achieve all this and everything works just fine except the revision deletion.

This code will delete entries from `my_entity_revision` table but not from `my_entity_revision_field_data` table:

```
$this->myEntityStorage->deleteRevision($revision_id)
```

Any ideas why this might happen? Thanks.

Here is my entity annotation:

```
@ContentEntityType(
   id = "my_entity",
   label = @Translation("My entity"),
   bundle_label = @Translation("My Entity type"),
   handlers = {
     "list_builder" = "Drupal\my_entity\Controller\MyEntityListBuilder",
     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
     "access" = "Drupal\website_settings\MyEntityAccessControlHandler",
     "form" = {
       "default" = "Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm",
       "add" = "Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm",
       "edit" = "Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm",
       "delete" = "Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityDeleteForm"
     },
     "views_data" = "Drupal\my_entity\MyEntityViewsData",
   },
   base_table = "my_entity",
   data_table = "my_entity_field_data",
   revision_table = "my_entity_revision",
   revision_data_table = "my_entity_revision_field_data",
   translatable = TRUE,
   entity_revision_parent_id_field = "parent_id",
   entity_keys = {
     "id" = "id",
     "uuid" = "uuid",
     "bundle" = "type",
     "langcode" = "langcode",
     "revision" = "revision_id"
   },
   bundle_entity_type = "my_entity_type",
   field_ui_base_route = "entity.my_entity_type.edit_form",
   links = {
     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}",
     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}/edit",
     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}/delete",
     "revision" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}/revision/{my_entity_revision}/view",
     "version-history" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}/revisions"
   }
)
```

And my baseFieldDefinition:

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Website settings entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    // Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
    $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
      ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the Website settings entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['revision_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Revision ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The paragraphs entity revision ID.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('unsigned', TRUE);

    $fields['type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Type'))
      ->setDescription(t('The website settings bundle type.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'website_settings_type')
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['langcode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('language')
      ->setLabel(t('Language code'))
      ->setDescription(t('The paragraphs entity language code.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE);

    $fields['uid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Authored by'))
      ->setDescription(t('The user ID of the website settings author.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setDefaultValueCallback('Drupal\website_settings\Entity\WebsiteSettings::getCurrentUserId')
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    // We set display options for the view as well as the form.
    // Users with correct privileges can change the view and edit configuration.
    $fields['title'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Title'))
      ->setSettings(array(
        'default_value' => '',
        'max_length' => 255,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -6,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -6,
      ))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['status'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
      ->setLabel(t('Published'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDefaultValue(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Authored on'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the website settings was created.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed on'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the website settings was last updated.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['revision_uid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Revision user ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The user ID of the author of the current revision.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
      ->setQueryable(FALSE)
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE);

    $fields['parent_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Parent ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the parent entity of which this entity is referenced.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'my_entity')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE);

    $fields['langcode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('language')
      ->setLabel(t('Language code'))
      ->setDescription(t('The language code of ContentEntityExample entity.'));

    return $fields;
  }
```

Comment: You should share at least your entity class and its annotation.

Comment: I have added the annotation and defaultBaseFields funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Is your entity extending the RevisionableInterface and RevisionLogInterface or the ContentEntityInterface ?

Otherwise it could be a drupal core issue ..

Other having the same (or is this you ?): https://www.drupal.org/node/2818053

Known issue (only with media): https://www.drupal.org/node/1239558

Comment: I am extending the ContentEntityInterface which extends the RevisionableInterface. It looks like it's a drupal bug. The rows in `node_field_revisions` table are not deleted as well.

Comment: have you checked @Berdir answer ? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95200/how-to-create-custom-entity-in-drupal-8