# How to make custom entity type revisionable with existing content?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to make a custom entity (with existing data!) revisionable, but I run into multiple very serious issues including schema update errors, difficulties with creating revision data for existing content, and so on...

Has anyone done something similar successfully? Is there a fairly simple way to do it?

Comment: see here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95200/how-to-create-custom-entity-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is highly complicated and there is currently no easy for such a switch.

[Upgrade path between revisionable / non-revisionable entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/2721313) is the core issue to make this easier. You could rely on the patch there but I'm not sure if it is fully working right now.